# Can't create new android project from command line

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to create a new android project from command line. I am following tutorial from [http://developer.android.com/](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html#CommandLine). In the tutorial, first they ask me to list the all available platforms installed on my system using `./android list targets` command. This gives me the following result,

```
irfan@outerheavenY500Ubuntu:~/Android/Sdk/tools$ ./android list targets
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-21"
     Name: Android 5.0.1
     Type: Platform
     API level: 21
     Revision: 2
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in, AndroidWearRound, AndroidWearSquare, AndroidWearRound, AndroidWearSquare
 Tag/ABIs : android-wear/armeabi-v7a, android-wear/x86, default/armeabi-v7a, default/x86, default/x86_64
----------
id: 2 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:21"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 1
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 5.0.1 (API level 21)
     Libraries:
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in, AndroidWearRound, AndroidWearSquare, AndroidWearRound, AndroidWearSquare
 Tag/ABIs : google_apis/x86
```

Then I try to execute the following command from to create a new project,

```
./android create project --target 1 --name MyFirstApp2 \ --path /home/irfan/AndroidProjects/MyFirstApp2 --activity MyActivity \ --package com.example.myfirstapp2
```

But this gives me the following error, `Error: Argument 'com.example.myfirstapp2' is not recognized.`

From the tutorial I follow this following command structure to create a new project,

```
./android create project --target <target-id> --name MyFirstApp \
--path <path-to-workspace>/MyFirstApp --activity MyActivity \
--package com.example.myfirstapp
```

If I am following the structure correctly, can anyone point me out what else am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `\` characters from your command. These are new line connectors which you don't need. Your command should look like:

```
./android create project --target 1 --name MyFirstApp2 --path /home/irfan/AndroidProjects/MyFirstApp2 --activity MyActivity --package com.example.myfirstapp2
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the backslashes. You also want to [add the path](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm) `~/Android/Sdk/tools` to your `$PATH`. That way you can call `android` and `adb` from any directory.

```
cd
PATH=$PATH:~/Android/Sdk/tools
export PATH
android create project --target 1 --name MyFirstApp2 --path ./MyFirstApp2 --activity MyActivity --package com.example.myfirstapp2
```

Comment: Thank you. One more question - why do I have to use the `export PATH` command to make the change permanent. I opened the ~/.profile and /etc/profile files after the export command, but those were unchanged.

Comment: You have to add the setting and exporting of the PATH in your .profile for it to be permanent. Otherwise its just for the duration of your terminal.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too, but where am I exporting? Which files is being changed in this process? Cause I opened both ~/.profile and /etc/profile and non of them hold the path value, and hack they don't have the paths I had already.